adjustbox gives "Undefined control sequence" error only in a figure caption, but not in a subcaption or normal text
I'm using \adjustbox for background color highlighting to emphasize certain text. It works in normal text and subcaptions, but strangely, not in figure captions! The resulting PDF looks fine, but I get errors in the log. What is happening?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{As expected, \adjustbox{bgcolor=yellow}{highlight} in subcaption is ok.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Unexpectedly, \adjustbox{bgcolor=yellow}{highlight} in normal caption is NOT ok! It visually works but produces an ``Undefined control sequence'' error.}
\end{figure}

And, \adjustbox{bgcolor=yellow}{highlight} works just fine in normal text.

\end{document}

Errors:
! Undefined control sequence.
\@adjustbox #1->\edef \adjbox@line 
                                   {\the \inputlineno }\let \collectbox@mode...
l.16 ... an ``Undefined control sequence'' error.}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@adjustbox ...ent \relax \let \adjbox@collectbox 
                                                  \@collectbox \let \adjbox@...
l.16 ... an ``Undefined control sequence'' error.}

[... and a bunch more similar errors...]

This happens in a fresh new project on Overleaf.

This is because the argument of regular \captions are fragile in the sense that they move; they eventually end up in the List of Figures (or Tables), and therefore need to be written to the .lof (or .lot) which requires expansion. In essence, you need to \protect certain macros that cause issues with this process.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{As expected, \adjustbox{bgcolor=yellow}{highlight} in subcaption is ok.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Unexpectedly, \protect\adjustbox{bgcolor=yellow}{highlight} in normal caption is NOT ok! It visually works but produces an ``Undefined control sequence'' error.}
\end{figure}

And, \adjustbox{bgcolor=yellow}{highlight} works just fine in normal text.

\end{document}

Alternatively, you can specify a different optional argument for the .lof entry using \caption[<lof>]{<document>} where <lof> doesn't use \adjustbox. Of course, if it's different and still uses something that causes issues, \protect there would also be helpful.
\captions of sub-floats don't end up in the LoF necessarily, hence there is no error. For them to be included you have to pass the package option list=true (at which you'll see another error for those \captions that still use \adjustbox).
